# Best elements for downhole and high temperature circuits

Tags: capacitor, resistors, design, datalogger

I want to design a data-logger with PIC MCUs. This data-logger is going to work in chamber in the oil wells in the depth o 500 meters. and it is going to record temperature and pressure for 20 hours.

The pressure in that depth is about 9000 PSI and the temperature is about 130 degreeC. I want to know what kind of elements is the best elements for this project. I mean if I need a **1uF** capacitor, which kind of capacitors is my best choice?  Electrolytes? Polyester? Ceramics? Multi-layer? Which one is less temperature sensitive? What about the resistors? and also all the other elements.

Please shed any light you can on this issue. Any point will really highly appreciate. Does any body have similar experience?

Comment: Set aside plenty of time for experimentation and failure; you aren't likely to get this right in one go.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I think so also. But the points that you will share with me, reduce the number of failures ;)

Comment: This is NOT meant to be rude - just cautionary. You don't know enough to ask good questions in order to know enough :-( :-). eg asking capacitor questions as you do suggests a very minor level of knowledge. There are few situations where it would be justified allowing you to do this. eg even a PhD student doing this for a thesis might expect a lab tech to be involved. If mF is milliFarad (1000 uF) then why do you need it? As well as temperature issues, some capacitor types are prone to impact effects. Find some basic real world capacitor reference material and start reading.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thank you dear Russell. It was 1uF BTW :D

Comment: @TheGoodUser-Amir I suspected you might have unit confusion :-). mF is (if anything) milli-Farad = 1000 micro-Farad. Olin seems to delight in taking people at face value when they commit this error and answering accordingly. | "Wet" aluminum electrolytics will tend to be unsuitable if you want to reuse them. For single 20 hour "journeys" they can be suitable but their are better alternatives. Lower grade ceramics (which are the ones with best capacitance per volume)may lose 95% of their rated capacitance at your down-hole temperatures.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have borehole experience, but I do have a lot of generalized experience, including space environments.

First, temperature. PICs won't do it. Go look up some data sheets. Their max is 85 C. You need MCUs rated for automotive or full mil-spec temperature (125 C). The same applies to all other components - full automotive (not industrial) or mil ratings.

Second, pressure. That's easy, no special pressure requirements on your circuits. The reason is simple: if you're going to operate the circuit at ambient pressure, you have to allow ambient materials into your electronics. And water and drilling mud are not what you want inside your data logger. This leads to the biggie:

Third, housing. You must learn to build hermetically sealed housings for your units, and they must withstand temperature and pressure. Think lots of stainless steel. And finally,

Test facilities. If you do not have the ability to apply a good replica of the operating conditions (temperature, pressure, material), and if you do not use this ability to run prolonged stress tests on your product, you are doomed.

Answer (score 3):

Microchip has devices qualified for [fairly high temperatures](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/technology/hightemperature/) (up to 150 C), which would seem to cover your requirement.

If you need to go higher, there are suppliers for devices qualified for a brief nasty life at 225 C or higher, but they are 8031, not PICs. Naturally, the performance tends towards the dismal and the price astronomical. At some point floating gate program storage becomes impractical and you have to resort to mask, fuse OTP or other nonvolatile memory technologies.

At only 130 C max you actually have many choices open- it's only slightly outside the mil temperature range -55 to 125 C. Try to use C0G caps where possible. For 1mF you can find plenty of electrolytic caps rated for 130 to 150C - things only get exotic at higher temperatures.

I suggest specifying a high Tg (glass transition temperature) PCB material.

Edit: yes, you have to keep the high pressure out or you will have a lot of difficulties. Any commercial environmental chamber should be able to get to 130 C or much higher so that should not be an issue.

Comment: With all due respect, environment may be an issue. You can't test pressure and temperature separately - well, you can, but it's asking for trouble. So you need a facility which will do both simultaneously, and that's a bit rarer.

Comment: It would not be too hard to put a homemade pressure chamber inside an environmental chamber- these things are small- although 9000 psi is on the high side. So the walls would have to be thick. The MEs I work with tend to shrug at this sort of stuff- and it keeps the machinists busy.

Comment: Yup. Just as long as it gets done. And putting a pressure tank in the oven is going to do wonders for the cycle times for different temps.